# its related to beans use in jsp

Tags: jsp, javabeans

`<jsp:useBean name="beanname" property="propertyname"/>`how to access the value of a bean property. We can do this by using above syntax  but i want to increment the value of this property how it is possible please please help me. I cant complete my project without it

Answer (score -1):

If I'm correct you have Bean class provide this class with package discription ex. exp.DemoBean. in jsp tag. After doing use this name value as object and call methods in your bean class.